# Computing Significance of Cumulative Improvement Between Test Variants

Tags: statistics

Given a test with two variants ($A$ and $B$), entrants of the test are randomly assigned into a variant with equal probability. A function exists to compute the score of any entrant $i$.

How can one compute the confidence that: the total scores of entrants in $A$ being greater than or equal to the total score for $B$ is significant?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on this ... not entirely sure what the question is